# Django:Error trying to add data in postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, templates

I get an error(The view crud.views.insertEmp didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.) whenever I try to insert data to my database through the insert.html template. I;m using postgres as my database. Any assistance in identifying the bug will be highly appreciated.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'employee'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from crud.models import Employee
from django.contrib import messages


def showEmp(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.all()
    context = {"data": employee}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)


def insertEmp(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('emp_name') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('occupation') and request.POST.get('salary') and request.POST.get('gender'):
            saveRecord = Employee() 
            saveRecord.emp_name = request.POST.get('emp_name')
            saveRecord.email = request.POST.get('email')
            saveRecord.occupation = request.POST.get('occupation')
            saveRecord.salary = request.POST.get('salary')
            saveRecord.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
            saveRecord.save()
            messages.success(request, "Employee " +
                             saveRecord.emp_name + "  is added succesfully.")
        return render(request, "insert.html")

    else:
        return render(request, "insert.html")
```

inser.html

```
<center>
        <h1>Insert data into Postgresql</h1>
        <hr>

        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table border="">

                <tr>
                    <td>Employee Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder=" Enter employee name.." name="emp_name""></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input type=" text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Occupaton</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="occupation">
                            <option selected disabled=true>-- Select occupation --</option>
                            <option value="">Programmer</option>
                            <option value="">HR</option>
                            <option value="">Sales Manager</option>
                            <option value="">Designer</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter salary" name="salary"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male |
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Insert"></td>
                    <td>
                        {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                        <b style="color:green;">{{message}}</b>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
        </form>

    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

*The way you structure your code may cause the return of None*, try to follow this example :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def insertEmp(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('emp_name') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('occupation') and request.POST.get('salary') and request.POST.get('gender'):
            saveRecord = Employee() 
            saveRecord.emp_name = request.POST.get('emp_name')
            saveRecord.email = request.POST.get('email')
            saveRecord.occupation = request.POST.get('occupation')
            saveRecord.salary = request.POST.get('salary')
            saveRecord.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
            saveRecord.save()
            messages.success(request, "Employee " +
                         saveRecord.emp_name + "  is added succesfully.")
        
            # Redirect to the same page (you can change the page to fit your needs)
            return redirect('.')
        else:
            # Not all required fields are present
            messages.error(request, "Please fill all the fields")
            # Also redirect the user to the same page
            return redirect('.')

    else:
        return render(request, "insert.html")
```

Comment: It's still not saving in the db,the else statement works which means the record is not being saved

Comment: Try to log `request.POST` in the console to see if all fields are correctly set

Comment: This is the log:
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['36aFhK1mVhOSnGiKYObxJo2nMKmKxXTceGgA1n7lAWho1gUF'], 'emp_name': ['Jane'], 'email': ['janedoe@outlook.com'], 'occupation': [''], 'salary': ['$ 10000'], 'gender': ['F']}>
Internal Server Error: /insert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/dev/employee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)